# vuejs How to detect data changes in a function from grand-child component when an array data changes from grand-parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm making a map interface to manage the map-related data. like link, nodes, vertex, and so on.
I'm facing the issue that I'm not sure how to detect changes in a grand-child component when data changes from grandparent component. Please advise me.

component tree:

1. grand parent: map container + tables to display map data(import map(child))
2. parent: map + leaflet-draw customized component (import edit-map(child))
3. (grand)child: leaflet-draw customized component

Using Vuex to share data

1. grandparent: get data(vuex), display, catch the updated data(completed) - ok, no problem
2. grand-child: add, edit, delete data. updated data will be sent to vuex. - ok, no problem

issue: Users can modify data also by using a table in grandparent.
problem: not sure how to detect changed data from grand-child component.

I can see the object values are changes automatically when I change data in the table... but I really have zero ideas on how to detect that changes in grand-child component...

let me know if you need more info.

Edited:
I've converted leaflet-draw vanilla js to grand-child component. All my codes are written in < .s .cript> </> above export default { data(), methods: {}, compueted:{} }. Only mounted() hook is used to display the component to parent(map) component. This is why I have no idea how to detect changes....

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the problem. If in the grand-parent and grand-children, both are able to update the vuex store, then you do not need to "detect" the change. Having a getter in grand-children getting the value of the store is sufficient. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: @DavidAlvarez  You're right. Forgot to mention that grand-child component's codes are all in <script></script> tag. All my functions are not in export default {} ... That's why I can't think of how to use it... I've edited the post. thx!

Comment: Is there a reason your functions are outside?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights yeap.. I think it's might be vuejs specific..? I'm not sure.. anyway when making a wraaper(converting a vanilla js to a component) adding methods in methods:{} won't work at all(I don't know why, it didn't work when I add them into methods: {}).

Comment: Functions inside `methods` have to be called elsewhere in a lifecycle method or DOM event. I'd recommend refactoring all your code to be inside the module, otherwise you can't use props or Vuex in any of your functions (not 100% sure on this but pretty sure).

Comment: Either way it's best practice to have all your functionality inside